# Reuse exceptions defined by libraries

Tags: java, exception

I have quite a lot of libraries in my project and all of them define quite a lot of exceptions, would it be a bad plan to throw these exceptions(when they have a fitting name and description) in my code instead of defining my own ones?

And what about throwing exceptions that are defined in the core libraries but maybe not are intended for your purpose?
For example throwing `java.security.acl.NotOwnerException` when a user can't delete a picture because they are not the owner, even though the permissions of my users have nothing to do with acl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's defintiely not a good idea. When I as a support programmer see a `java.security.acl.NotOwnerException` I would assume that the problem has something to do with access control lists and start my research in that direction. It might take some man-hours for me to come to the conclusion that we aren't even using ACLs and the exception was just a red herring.

But when I see a `com.ourorganization.ourapp.NotOwnerException` I know that it must be a (actual or perceived) violation of our own business logic and I got a much hotter lead to follow.

Also keep in mind that exceptions are full-fledged classes and thus can have plenty of additional features. When you don't use the classes for their intended purpose, these features might not work as intended. This can cause a lot of confusion for a user of your classes.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a "primarily opinion-based" question, it's hard to tell, although I do have a concrete argument below. :-)

FWIW, I would recommend using your own appropriate exceptions, and only certain fairly general ones from the JDK that are clearly intended for reuse. My concrete reason for that is that any time you start using exceptions from other libraries, you increase your linkage to that library, and make it harder to replace it with another one when you want to. That applies less to the JDK, of course, as you're pretty much linked to it if you're using Java, but I certainly wouldn't use an exception from the `java.security.acl` package if the code in question doesn't have anything to do with ACLs!

Answer (score 2):

> When faced with choosing the type of exception to throw, you can
> either use one written by someone else — the Java platform provides a
> lot of exception classes you can use — or you can write one of your
> own.
>
> You should write your own exception classes if you answer yes to
> any of the following questions; otherwise, you can probably use
> someone else's.
>
> • Do you need an exception type that isn't represented by those in the
> Java platform?
>
> • Would it help users if they could differentiate your
> exceptions from those thrown by classes written by other vendors?
>
> • Does your code throw more than one related exception?
>
> • If you use someone else's exceptions, will users have access to those exceptions?
> A similar question is, should your package be independent and
> self-contained?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/creating.html

I would not use imported library's exceptions, because they probably serve a specific purpose for that library.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the common exceptions, like IllegalState and such, but avoid using some specific "weirder" exceptions (such as your acl example), since it might give the wrong impression.

I would replace NotOwnerException with a normal SecurityException, since you should've validated already that a non-owner isn't able to delete pictures that aren't his. So essentially the exception should never be thrown in the first place.

Comment: Throwing an `IllegalStateException` isn't very explanatory, because it says nothing about what state is meant and what's illegal about it. But you could create an own exception which extends IllegalStateException and is more specific.

Comment: True, but that's why you also have the exception message ;) IllegalStateException("project TakeOverTheWorld must be active") is very descriptive, IMO.

Comment: Indeed, and I use it in the "this should never happen" situations, not as a catchable exception.

Comment: @Kayman Ah, the infamous ThisShouldNeverHappenException we all love so much when it appears in a stack-trace :)